# How to autosave blockchain?

Tags: monerod-commands

I am running a Monero node on one of my Windows computers (bitmonero.exe) and it is fully synchronized with the network. Occasionally, I need to restart this computer without warning and do not get a chance to save the blockchain. Is there any way for me to configure a setting to autosave the Monero blockchain every hour or so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run bitmonerod with the option "--db-sync-mode safe" and it will persist every change immediately. Then if your system crashes or restarts suddenly, there will be no data lost and bitmonerod will pick up wherever it left off the next time it starts.

Comment: How do you chain arguments to run the executable (windows)?  Let's say I want to point bitmonerod to a directory that includes the monero block chain, plus I want to use --db-sync-mode safe. (bitmonerod --data-dir H:\location_of_blockchain --db-sync-mode safe) ?

Comment: yes, just keep appending to the command line.